# How to set the bundle value in Spinner view?

Tags: java, android, fragment, bundle, spinner

There is a **spinner view** in the edit profile fragment.
I want to set the user data of nationality(value retrieved from bundle) in the spinner.
My tries are:

//CountryData

```
 String[] country = {"Country", "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria.......... };
```

//Spinner

```
    private void setSpinner(View view) {
        // this is the spinner of country name
        Spinner spin = view.findViewById(R.id.et_address);
        ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_text, country);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner
        spin.setAdapter(aa);
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if (position != 0) {
                    spinnerValue = country[position];

                    System.out.println("country position is" + spinnerValue);
                    ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
```

//Get data from ProfileFragments using bundle

```
 public void getBundleData() {
        bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            clientFullname1 = bundle.getString("client_fullname");
            dob1 = bundle.getString("dob");
            email1 = bundle.getString("email");
            phone1 = bundle.getString("phone");
            nationality1 = bundle.getString("nationality");

        }
    }
```

//Set retrieved data from bundle to textView

```
 public void setValue() {
        etFullName.setText(clientFullname1);
        etDateOfBirth.setText(dob1);
        etEmailAddress.setText(email1);
        etPhoneDetails.setText(phone1);

        etAddress.setText(nationality1);  //Note: the author has set this nationality value in 
                                           textView instead of spinner but he is trying to set the bundle value in spinner
    }
```

Comment: ArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_text, country) what is country here. where you are declaring and assigning value in country object

Comment: @DharmenderManral , I updated question,please have a glance once.

Comment: @DharmenderManral following provided code does not include any ways to set the bundle values in a spinner. So Please read the question carefully.

Comment: can you show me how and where you are putting data in bundle and make sure nationality object should not be null

Comment: I have update my answer can you please check again

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code its working.

```
  //activity xml
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/myToolbar">
<Spinner
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="50dp"
  android:id="@+id/spinner01"/></RelativeLayout>

 //Activity code
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    getBundleData();
    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner01);
    ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[]{nationality1});
    spinner.setAdapter(aa);


    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (position != 0) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"click on spinner item",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

  }


public void getBundleData() {
    bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        clientFullname1 = bundle.getString("client_fullname");
        dob1 = bundle.getString("dob");
        email1 = bundle.getString("email");
        phone1 = bundle.getString("phone");
        nationality1 = bundle.getString("nationality");

    }
  }


 }
```